# TypeError: 'Sheet' object is not callable when combining data across excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd, xlwt

I am now working on combining data for 2 excel file. my approach is to use `xlwt` to create a new excel and corresponding sheet. and then use for loop to write into the newly created excel file. my code is as below,

```
#......
    wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet_0 = wbk.add_sheet('A')
    sheet_1 = wbk.add_sheet('B')
    wbk.save(os.path.join(currentPath, gsheet.cell(gsr, 2).value) + FullName + " " + time_now + ".xls")

    wkbk = xlrd.open_workbook(
        os.path.join(currentPath, gsheet.cell(gsr, 2).value) + FullName + " " + time_now + ".xls")
    wb_merge = copy(wkbk)
    wsheet_0 = wb_merge.get_sheet(0)
    wsheet_1 = wb_merge.get_sheet(1)

    workbook_merge_0 = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join(currentPath, filename0), formatting_info=True)
    sheet_merge_0 = workbook_merge_0.sheet_by_index(0)

    for r in range(0, total_row_0):
        for c in range(0, total_col_0):
            wsheet_1.write(r, c, sheet_merge_0(r, c).value)
#......
```

when i am running the whole code, error show `TypeError: 'Sheet' object is not callable`, pointing to the last row, i.e. `wsheet_1.write(r, c, sheet_merge_0(r, c).value)`

Any suggestion can be provided? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sheet_merge_0` is a `Sheet`. You're trying to call it as if it were a function. You probably wanted to call its `cell` method, as you did with other sheets earlier in the same code?

Comment: Well, the basic problem is obvious: `sheet_merge_0` is a `Sheet`, but you tried to access it like a function.  Look into the `Sheet` class documentation; find the correct syntax for getting a particular cell from a sheet.  The class should have an access method, or perhaps you simply need brackets instead of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks! i am amended to `sheet_merge_0.cell(r, c).value` and it works perfectly great!